# Apache proxy follow redirect without going back to the browser

Tags: apache, redirect, proxy

I am interested in creating an apache proxy configuration which will allow me to follow redirect at the proxy level not at the client/browser level.

For example, if a user goes to example.com/downloads/file1 the reverse proxy would send the traffic to downloads1.example.com/file. When the file is not present on that server the downloads1.example.com server will return a 301 redirect to downloads2.example.com/file. this 301 redirect should be handled by the apache proxy instead of being passed to the browser

client -> apache reverse proxy -> server with files -> redirect 301 to another server -> apache reverse proxy -> new server with files -> apache proxy -> client

Is it possible to implement this with apache reverse proxy?

Comment: Not that I know of.  mod_proxy returns the response to the client, it does not react to it (besides editing links with mod_proxy_http).